# Проверка результата AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

Добрый день! не могу разобраться как проверить значение возвращаемое ajax.
Типовая задача- авторизация и редирект, сервер в случае удачной авторизации возвращает  через echo login, я думал cпросто сверять результат как в коде ниже, но вариант оказался не рабочий.
При выводе в консоль всё ок, в случае верной авторизации в консоли выводится login.

```
var session=makeid();
var login=$("input[name='login']").val();
var password=$("input[name='password']").val();
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'auth.php',
    data: { login:login,
            password:password,
            session: session

    },
    success:function(data){
        console.log(data);
      if(data=="login"){
         $.cookie('session',session);
         $.cookie('login',login);
         $(location).attr('href','https://some.site');
      } else{
          $('.grid_content_login_div').text("Логин или пароль введены не верно!");
      }
    }
})
})
```

Comment: а кукисы добавляются нормально?

Comment: @Владислав,забыл уточнить, оператор возвращает результат else.т.е. выводит "Логин или пароль введены не верно!", соответственно первое условие не выполняется и куки не создаются.

Comment: что именно консоль выдает при console.log(data) ? покажи echo в php

Comment: @Владислав, нет, не json. php возвращает echo "login";, в консоли - login

Comment: @Владислав    if ($count>0){
$session_query="INSERT INTO active_user SET user_id='".$login."',session='".$session."' WHERE id=1"; 
mysqli_query($con,$session);

echo "login";


}else{
    echo "something wrong";

}

Comment: честно, не вижу ошибки в показаном коде. Так, стреляя, попробуй другое слово выведи. ОК например. Проверь еще каким типом является data. Мне кажется, что ты получаешь не string.

Comment: "в консоли - login" - при чем здесь авторизация/шмавторизация? Вы хотите сказать, что проверка `data=="login"` дает неправильный результат.